# Declaring a function with a lot of pointers

Tags: c

How can I declare f as pointer to function (pointer to pointer to integer, double) to *return pointer to pointer to integer* ?

I have tried a lot of variants including:

```
(int**)(f*)(int**,double)
(**int)(f*)(int**,double)
*(int)(f*)(int**,double)
```

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keeping the focus on older questions which still don't have an answer.

Comment: Hi, done that now, sorry for marking it so late.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be:

```
int**(*f)(int**,double)
```

Which according to [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/) means:

> declare f as pointer to function (pointer to pointer to int, double) returning pointer to pointer to int

I don't believe you can put parens around the return type, and the `*` for the pointer-to-function part needs to be on the left of the declared name.

Answer (score 4):

The function signature:

```
int** func(int**, double);
```

The function pointer declaration:

```
int** (*f)(int**, double);
```

Comment: I like the way you presented this. In shows that you just write the function down, and then replace the name with `(*f)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the answer :

```
int** (*f)(int**, double)
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer#Example_in_C

[How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: Thanks :) Yeah, pointers to functions are real useful, but twisted. Xolve gives a good breakdown of this one.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int** (*f)(int**, double);
```

Answer (score 1):

I read your description, broke it in parts and here it is:

```
int **     (*f)(  int **,         double)
 ^           ^       ^               ^
 |           |       |               |
 |       pointer to  |               |
 |       function    |               |
 |                   |               |
 |                 pointer to        |
 |                 pointer to        |
 |                 integer           |
 |                                double
 |
 |
return pointer to pointer to integer
```

Its actually this simple.

You should read **[C FAQ on Declarations](http://c-faq.com/decl/cdecl1.html)** Its explains them in a very simple and comprehensive way.